# Getting the input from the user to create a csv file

Tags: python, csv, input, operating-system

Having a bit of a trouble here. I'd like to create a CSV file with the name that the user inputs in the program. I've checked on the site and tried multiple solutions. For me, this one should have worked :

```
CSVfilename = "synonymes.csv"
modifiedCSV = input("Enter file name : ")
os.rename(CSVfilename, modifiedCSV +".csv")

csv_file = open(CSVfilename, "w", encoding='utf-8', newline = '')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
```

But this doesn't work. How can I get the input of the user before creating the CSV file or allow the user to rename it?

I'm using the csv module in Python3. I Don't get an error, it just Don't create the csv file I will be using later.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want to create a file or rename an existing one?

Comment: I want the user to be able to create it and name it as he wants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify your code a bit. You can just ask the user to input the file name and then create a file. To do that you can just open the file in `w` mode that will create the file if it doesn't exist (and overwrite the file if it does exist):

```
import csv
import os

path = 'folder/path/here'
name = input("Enter file name : ") + '.csv'
csvFileName = os.path.join(path,name)
```

Now you can work with your file:

```
with open(csvFileName, 'w') as csv_file:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ',')
    csvWriter.writerow(#<Your data here>#)
```

Note: just posting as an answer for formatting reason

Comment: I'll try this and tell you what I got

Comment: I've just edited my answer to add the file extension that I forgot. I tried this piece of code and it worked for me. The file is created in the same directory as the script....

Comment: @BeatJuice I've added a few lines to specify the full path where the file should be created.

Answer (score 0):

Writing here so I can put the code.

```
NomdufichierCSV = input("Entrez le nom de votre fichier : ") + ".csv"

with open(NomdufichierCSV, "w", encoding='utf-8', newline = '') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow("Hello World")
```

I still don't get the CSV file created in the folder… I don't understand why… even more now that I know it worked for you.

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't work, I tried the exact code that you posted and worked for me...have you tried looking for the file somewhere else in your computer?

Comment: Indeed it created it but in a total other folder, I Don't know why. Anyway this works :) Thanks dude!

Comment: Ok, maybe it created it in the python executable folder. Anyway, you can maybe specify the full path, I'll update my answer.